# Sci fi short story/novel where ads are projected into dreams

Tags: story-identification, books

Looking for a sci fi short story/novel where ads are projected into dreams. I know about the *Futurama* episode s1e6, but I read this in my childhood well before *Futurama*. So it should be from a classic sci-fi period, something like Philip Dick's time or so.

The story goes like this: there's so much ads that they are even transmitted into people's dreams, so people pay top dollar to get into underground "resorts" that basically shield them from these ads.

The other possibility of course is that I also dreamt about this novel, and it was projected by *Futurama* marketers.

Comment: Plus 1 just for this:- "The other possibility of course is that I also dreamt about this novel, and it was projected by Futurama marketers."

Comment: This sounds exactly the sort of thing Philip K. Dick would have written about, but to my surprise I can't find stories like this in my PKD anthologies.

Comment: I wonder if it isn't Frederik Pohl and Cyril Kornbluth's novel _[The Space Merchants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Space_Merchants)_ or its followup _[The Merchants' War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Merchants'_War_(Pohl_novel))_. The projected ads are familiar but the resorts aren't.  Anyway, Pohl wrote a lot of stuff in this vein.

Comment: Sounds a bit like a cross between Dark City & Paycheck (Philip K. Dick). I think it was the novelisation of the Dark City movie that had them doing different marketing techniques (I seem to remember her buying two fridges in the one day) and then 're-setting' the city and everyones memory.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paycheck_(novelette)
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1919012.Dark_City

Paycheck is indeed a 'memeory reset' by PKD.

Comment: I remember a similar one in which audio ads were projected into just about any space that had people in it (including moving vehicles), and the company running resorts advertised by shielding sections of road (drivers got a rare period of silence punctuated by a short "this silence brought to you by..." message every minute). Dream ads were rumoured to be the latest development.  There was also one day per year in which no legally-binding agreements could be made.  Does any of that sound familiar?